# GPO doesn't take efffect when applied to a Security Group

Tags: windows-server-2008, active-directory, group-policy

I have a GPO I created that adds a registry value `(USER CONFIGURATION -> PREFERENCES -> WINDOW SETTINGS -> REGISTRY)`.  I want it to target a specific group of users that are in a security group I created.  The security group I created is called `Remote Access VPN Users`.  I've added myself to said Security Group (did this over a week ago), confirmed replication.  Under the SCOPE tab, under Security Filtering, I removed `Authenticated Users` and added the `Remote Access VPN Users` security group.  Saved and forced gpupdate but it never creates the registry entry.

I tested using Group Policy Results and it keeps telling me that the GPO was Denied because it's inaccessible.  Why is it not applying to my Security Group?  When I removed the Security Group and add `Authenticated Users` back to the GPO Scope filtering it works as expected.  However, I don't want this to apply to `Authenticated Users`

Do I need to use a Distribution Group instead of a Security group?  The policy is linked to my domain.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you remove authenticated user, you need to add an entry, domain computer/read in the security. Its a new security MS fixed last year

[image]

For the explication please see there;

https://blogs.technet.microsoft.com/askds/2016/06/22/deploying-group-policy-security-update-ms16-072-kb3163622/

Comment: Thanks for the quick answer, but where do you exactly mean I need to add an entry? And what type of entry?

Comment: @drpcken please see the edit, now better :)

Comment: @yagmoth555 - I'm surprised this doesn't come up more than it does here.  MS was very stealthy about releasing that update last summer.

Comment: @TheCleaner I agree! my theory, from what I seen at job, is that old gpo & old user that got a cached profile seem less impacted, only new user or if you create a new gpo. Kinda a timebomb.